# Photoshop script ignores transparency on saving into png (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, png, transparency, photoshop

For example I have a project with two layers. First layer is transparent. Second layer has a rect and its opacity is 50%.

After saving in a saved file the picture looks like as the opacity was 100% (fully opaque). How to solve this? I used the following function to save:

```
function SavePNG(saveFile){
    var opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    opts.PNGB = false;
    opts.quality = 100;
    pngFile = new File(saveFile);
    opts.includeProfile = true;
    app.activeDocument.exportDocument(pngFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
}
```

I used photoshop cs6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution in photoshop forums:

```
function SavePNG(saveFile){
    pngFile = new File(saveFile);

    var pngOpts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb; 
    pngOpts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG
    pngOpts.PNG8 = false; 
    pngOpts.transparency = true; 
    pngOpts.interlaced = false; 
    pngOpts.quality = 100;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(pngFile,ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,pngOpts);
}
```

At least this solution hasn't problems with transparency and works automatically without of showing dialogs

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the list of options

```
opts.transparency = true
```

Okay, try ExportOptionsSave

```
    function SavePNG(saveFile)
{
    var pngFile = new File(filePath);
    opts = new PNGSaveOptions();
    opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    opts.transparency = true
    opts.PNGB = false;
    opts.quality = 100;
    opts.includeProfile = true;

    activeDocument.saveAs(pngFile, opts, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

I normally use something along these line:

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var fileName = app.activeDocument.name;
var docName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.length -4)

// Set filePath and fileName to source path
filePath = srcDoc.path + '/' + app.activeDocument.name + '.png';

// duplicate image into new document
// =======================================================
var id2784 = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
var desc707 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id2785 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref508 = new ActionReference();
var id2786 = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
ref508.putClass( id2786 );
desc707.putReference( id2785, ref508 );
var id2787 = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
desc707.putString( id2787, docName );
var id2788 = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
var ref509 = new ActionReference();
var id2789 = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var id2790 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var id2791 = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref509.putEnumerated( id2789, id2790, id2791 );
desc707.putReference( id2788, ref509 );
executeAction( id2784, desc707, DialogModes.NO );

// save out the image
var pngFile = new File(filePath);
pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
pngSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
pngSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
pngSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE; pngSaveOptions.quality = 1;

activeDocument.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);

// close that saved png
app.activeDocument.close()
```

Comment: Of course the second way works, because I need to save it manually,  because Save dialog appears. But can you add to this at least how to setup a name of the file in this dialog? It takes the name correctly but if it is something in this directory with the same name then the name becomes "... copy.png"

Comment: It's not elegant but I get around that problem by duplicating the image and saving out that one.